# is numba a good choice to create program that reads from peripherial and calls python wrapped C code?

Tags: python, performance, numba

first of all I have never used numba, so my questions can have basic answers

I would like to write program that reads from peripheral device and processes data in real-time, problem is not in amount of data rather will numba address this quiestions or should I use good old C++/Rust:

1. I will call python wrappers to code in C (drivers and interact in realtime 10 times per second) so this code will be not compiled by numba, even though will numba create overhead because of it?
2. in processing I use a lot of math like FFT, problem is that I will also add GUI to my app and I would like to have at least 10 FPS, here I would also call wrappers to C/C++ code (dearImGUI other options are welcomed) is it possible to compile these with numba?

with C++/Rust I can achieve this easily but is it achievable with numba in python?

Comment: Numba only support basic Python code and (mostly) Numpy. There are some very rare Python module that support Numba but if it is not mentioned in the module, it will not work with Numba. At least not in njitted mode. AFAIK, there is an obj mode so to call Python code from njitted function but it is experimental (it sometimes cause CPython crashes) and has restricted usages.

Comment: It is not clear what is calling what, but if you want to call C code from Numba, this is AFAIK possible. For C++ code, AFAIK, it can only be done if the C++ functions are called `extern "C"`, so it is basically using the C ABI. AFAIK, C functions can call callback compiled with Numba if they are compiled as C-compatible functions (with restricted features).

Comment: If your goal is to mix C/C++/Rust code with Python, then Cython is certainly better suited for that (this is AFAIK what famous packages like SciPy does). Cython can also speed up Python codes (but not Numpy functions) and you can use Python modules/objects in Cython functions (as opposed to njitted functions).